# Firebase-admin doesn't send iOS APN notification

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I can send push notifications from `Firebase Console Notifications` to my iOS device, and it works perfectly being the app in foreground and background.

When I try to send them using `Firebase-admin by NodeJS` it only works when the app is in foreground, in background nothing happens.

I think that the communications between FCM-APNs are good because it works with the console.

This is my NodeJS code:

```
function sendFCM(registration_ids, data, collapseKey) {

    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        collapseKey : collapseKey,
        contentAvailable : true,
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };

    const payload = {
        data: data,
        notification: {
            title: "My title",
            text: "My description",
            sound : "default"
        }
    }

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registration_ids, payload, options)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
}
```

What do you think that it's happening? Do you know some way to log the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Server Protocol documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) indicates the key for notification text is `body`, not `text`.  See if this change makes a difference:

```
const payload = {
    data: data,
    notification: {
        title: "My title",
        body: "My description", // <= CHANGE
        sound : "default"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. There were two fails. First, the one that you said. Second, the firebase json was bad :(. Too many hours developing...